# Is there anyway to change the title on a pdf in a new window?

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to change the title on a pdf in a new window?  I've tried:

```
prntWin = window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + response);
prntWin.document.title = 'Testing';
```

And then

```
OpenWindow=window.open();
OpenWindow.document.write("<TITLE>Title Goes Here</TITLE>")
OpenWindow.document.write("<BODY BGCOLOR=pink>")
OpenWindow.document.write("data:application/pdf;base64, " + response);
OpenWindow.document.write("</BODY>")
OpenWindow.document.write("</HTML>")
OpenWindow.document.close()
```

And then

```
prntWin=window.open();
prntWin.document.write("<TITLE>Title Goes Here</TITLE>");
prntWin.document.write("data:application/pdf;base64, " + response);
prntWin.document.close();
```

and many other variations of the above.

Comment: nope sorry its up to the viewer.

Comment: Can I append the pdf to force a title?

Comment: By the title, do you mean the result of `<title>` tags in HTML pages?

Comment: yea title and hover has the base64encoded pdf.   The tab title and hover for the tab.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following (works in Chrome for me--haven't tested anything else):

```js
var file = 'data:application/pdf;base64,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';
var prntWin = window.open();
prntWin.document.write("<html><head><title>Title Goes Here</title></head><body>"
    + '<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="'+ file + '" '
    + 'type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="21"></body></html>');
prntWin.document.close();
```

You should be able to copy + paste that in the Chrome dev console. Be sure to allow popups, or it won't show.

Comment: Excellent Bro, I am looking for this solution