# Weird characters in pdf title

Tags: java, pdf

I have an app where I show a pdf that I have created previously just like that:

**Server side**

```
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> 
getMsgboxSummaryPdf(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){...

InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(report.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 

response = new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(new InputStreamResource(stream),
                new ReportsService().createPdfHeader(report), HttpStatus.OK);
return response;
}

/**
 * Create PDF header.
 *
 * @param report
 *            report to write PDF
 * @return PDF header
 */
public HttpHeaders createPdfHeader(String report) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "filename=sysparamspdf");
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");
    headers.setContentLength(report.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length);
    return headers;
}
```

**Client side**

```
 success :  function(response) {
            var data = this.toBinaryString(response.responseText);
            data = "data:application/pdf;base64,"+btoa(data);
            var window = this.createWindowPdf(data)
 ...

  toBinaryString: function(data) {
    var ret = [];
    var len = data.length;
    var byte;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        byte=( data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF )>>> 0;
        ret.push(String.fromCharCode(byte) );
    }
    return ret.join('');
},
```

**Result**
[image]
**Problem**

The report works fine except that I don´t know how I can change the strange characters that appear in the title of the pdfs viewer.

Could anyone give me an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a file name that was automatically generated.

Comment: please show `this.createWindowPdf` function, maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/33834393/1516873

Comment: Hi!, I have something like this:
<embed width=100% height=100% name="Prueba 2" title="Prueba" type="application/pdf" src="'+ params.pdfData +'"></embed>'

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set a filename via header:

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.add("content-disposition", "filename=" + fileName);
```

Then set the responseHeaders to your responseEntity.

Comment: Hi Benjamin thanks for the reply!. I´m using this code in  response = new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(new InputStreamResource(stream),
                new ReportsService().createPdfHeader(report), HttpStatus.OK);

Comment: Do you need to load the data via ajax and parse it in javascript? If you put the server url in your embed-tag it should work.