# How correctly receive pdf from backend and store in vue js data(state)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I correctly receive the PDF from this API endpint and store it inside vue state `this.invoicePDF`

I am trying to use a library called [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to handle the HTTP requests.

```
    axios.get('/product/invoiceId')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
```

How can I receive pdf from this endpoint correctly and store it inside `this.invoicePDF`?

Comment: you can refer this link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181514/download-pdf-file-with-node-and-vuejs`

Comment: It's a different case and even not answerd

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. Here you need to send `responseType: 'blob'` in request.

```
  axios.get({ 
    url: '/product/invoiceId',
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob'
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    this.invoicePDF = downloadUrl
    // this.downloadFile()
  })
```

In case if you want to download the file

```
  downloadFile() {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = this.invoicePDF;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I need to render it with vue router only. I assume iframe should be used in the new component with the required route correct?

Comment: yeah, you can use iframe.

Comment: I will check the solution and  check it as marked) Thanks once again

Comment: BTW I am using content-type application/pdf hope it will work with this solution

Comment: is responseType: 'blob' still needed in that case?

Comment: I think it's needed, you can try without it, let me know if that works

Comment: Is there any way to customize the title of the PDF? Because it shows a random string as the title which is probably generated by objectURL

Comment: you can try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834013/is-there-anyway-to-change-the-title-on-a-pdf-in-a-new-window